# Printing based on a range of numbers

Tags: python

Having trouble printing based on a range of numbers. How can I make this command more efficient or work?

Given A low inflation rate is below 3%, a moderate is 3% or higher but less than 5%, high inflation is more than 5% but less than 10% and any inflation rate at 10% or higher is hyper.

```
if inf_Rate <= 3:
    print("Type of inflation: Low")
elif inf_Rate in range(3, 5):
    print("Type of inflation: Moderate")
elif inf_Rate in range(5, 10):
    print("Type of inflation: High")
else:
    print(("Type of inflation: Hyper"))
```

Comment: What is the type of `inf_Rate`? `range` only contains integers, so you can't test floats using it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use normal comparisons, not `in range()`, if the numbers are floats.

```
if inf_Rate < 3:
    inf_type = 'Low'
elif inf_Rate < 5:
    inf_type = 'Moderate'
elif inf_rate < 10:
    inf_type = 'High'
else: 
    inf_type = 'Hyper'
print(f'Type of inflation: {inf_type}')
```

You don't need to test the bottom of each range, since the conditions are tested in order, and lower values are already precluded.

Also, your first condition doesn't match the givens. It's supposed to be *below* 3%, but your condition includes 3%.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `range` only works on ints, but it would be relatively easy to define your own `InflationRateRange` class where `__contains__` wraps the chained comparison approach.

```
class InflationRateRange(object):
  def __init__(self, low, high):
    self.low = low
    self.high = high
  def __contains__(self, val):
    return self.low <= val <= self.high
```

Now you can use floating point numbers.

```
2.7 in InflationRateRange(0, 3)
# True
```